Not able to connect to Gitea through WireGuard although NGINX works
I am not able to connect to Gitea through WireGuard VPN, but NGINX works. Also I can connect without WireGuard.
Setup:
Gitea runs in Docker on Alpine Linux on a Windows-hosted Oracle VM VirtualBox with a Bridged Adapter network.
WireGuard is configured as hub and spoke topology
The WireGuard IP of Alpine Linux is 10.10.0.5. The IP of Alpine Linux in Oracle VM VirtualBox is 192.168.10.5.
Gitea has http port 3000.
Problem:
When trying http://10.10.0.5:3000, there is no error; nothing is shown on page, it just loads forever or wget says Connecting to 10.10.0.5:3000 (10.10.0.5:3000) and hangs forever.
http://192.168.10.5:3000 works OK.
The same goes for all WireGuard nodes, but the one with Gitea. On that node http://10.10.0.5:3000 also works.
Notes:
NGINX runs on the same Alpine Linux in Docker with port 8080, and both http://10.10.0.5:8080 and http://192.168.10.5:8080 work.
Also, a similar setup: Gitea in Docker in Alpine Linux with WireGuard running on VPS works OK.
Network topology
There are three systems involved:

Alpine Linux with a WireGuard server running on a VPS with a static IP (13x.xxx.xxx.0). Its WireGuard IP address is 10.10.0.1.
Windows, which connects to the Internet via a local Internet provider through the provider's router. It functions as a WireGuard client. Its WireGuard IP address is 10.10.0.4 and local IP address is 192.168.10.4.
Alpine Linux running in VirtualBox hosted on the aforementioned Windows. This Alpine instance also operates as a WireGuard client. Its WireGuard IP address is 10.10.0.5 and local IP address is 192.168.10.5.

Wireguard network is 10.10.0.0 and it is wg0 interface.
Local network is 192.168.10.0 and it is eth0 interface in VirtualBox Alpine and Windows is connected to it. WireGuard server is not connected to the local network as it runs in cloud VPS and has its own static IP address.
Routing tables
Kernel IP routing table on Alpine in VirtualBox (netstat -rn)



Destination
Gateway
Genmask
Flags
MSS Window
irtt
Iface




0.0.0.0
192.168.10.1
0.0.0.0
UG
0 0
0
eth0


10.10.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0 0
0
wg0


172.17.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.0.0
U
0 0
0
docker0


192.168.10.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0 0
0
eth0



Kernel IP routing table on WireGuard server running in VPS (netstat -rn)



Destination
Gateway
Genmask
Flags
MSS Window
irtt
Iface




0.0.0.0
13x.xxx.xxx.0
0.0.0.0
UG
0 0
0
eth0


10.10.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0 0
0
wg0


13x.xxx.xxx.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0 0
0
eth0



Question:
What could be the problem here? What tools should I use to debug this?

I can't make out the full layout of your network – are the connections done through WireGuard in both cases or through a local network or something else? If they're supposed to take the same path, then what does a packet capture reveal about the differences? For example, does Alpine receive the packets equally in both cases (tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 'port 3000' or whichever interface it is expected to be) and does it forward them through to its docker0? If there's one tool that you should have handy the moment you do any routing, it's Wireshark/tcpdump...

I updated Network topology part. When trying tcpdump I can see packets received in all cases: 1. tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 'port 3000' reading http://192.168.10.5:3000 2. tcpdump -e -n -i wg0 'port 3000' reading http://10.10.0.5:3000 3. tcpdump -e -n -i wg0 'port 8080' reading http://10.10.0.5:8080

The solution is to add MTU = 1400 into WireGuard configuration file into [Interface] section. I found the solution here
https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/l02rmq/tcp_working_both_ways_but_http_stuck_after_header/
